# Display UIAlertView on certain date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I was wondering how I'd make a UIAlertView display on a certain date, for example, users download the iPhone application and then on the 12th August, a predetermined UIAlertView displays? How could I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API. It allows you to create and schedule local notification for your application, which will then be fired on the desired date, using a badge/popover/sound (same settings as for the remote notification API).

For your case you should specifically take a look at the [fire date](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate). Sample code would look moreless like this:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your message here";
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

This will fire a local notification with a "Your message here" text in one hour.